Using `and rsp,-16` for stack alignment in x86
Consider this "Hello world" x86 program:
    bits 64
    global main
    extern puts

    section .text
main:
    push rbp
    mov rdi, msg
    call puts
    pop rbp
    ret

    section .data
msg:db "Hello world!", 10, 0

I understand the purpose of the push rbp instruction is to align stack pointer to 16-byte boundary for the external subroutine puts. After this instruction, rsp will be misaligned by 8 bytes since rbp has the size of 8 bytes. But the call instruction will push the return address into the stack, so rsp will get decremented by 8 again. Then stack will be aligned before executing the first instruction in puts subroutine.
There are other ways to align the stack pointer. For example, the top answer from this related question suggests that I can do and rsp,-16 when I don't know whether the stack pointer is aligned or not. The above program might become
    bits 64
    global main
    extern puts

    section .text
main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    and rsp,-16  ; after this instruction, expect rsp to be divisible by 16 (0b10000)
    mov rdi, msg
    call puts
    mov rsp, rbp ; restore the old stack pointer
    pop rbp
    ret

    section .data
msg:db "Hello world!", 10, 0

What confuses me that if I do and rsp,-16 before call instruction, then after call implicitly push the return address to the stack, wouldn't the stack be misaligned by 8 bytes when executing the first instruction in puts subroutine? Maybe I misunderstood how to use and rsp,-16 correctly.

Yes, under most x86-64 calling conventions, the stack is misaligned by 8 on entry to a function. The puts function will adjust the stack by 16 * n + 8 bytes to bring it back into alignment. See opening discussion of this question.

@RaymondChen I am following System V ABI calling convention. I am now confused whether rsp should be divisible by 16 before call or rsp should be misaligned by 8 before call.

rsp should be divisible by 16 before the call, so the call itself will misalign it by 8. (so usually you don't need and rsp,-16, you just need to allocate an odd multiple of 8 bytes to restore alignment)

Okay, I think I figured out my misunderstanding. In System V ABI calling convention, it is required that the stack pointer must be 16-byte aligned (i.e. rsp % 16 == 0) right before the call instruction is executed.
In the first hello world example I wrote, upon entry to the main function, the stack pointer is misaligned by 8. Huh, why? Well, in Linux, the true entry point of the program is _start not main. The stack pointer is 16-byte aligned at the beginning of _start but is misaligned by 8 bytes after the program control is passed from _start to main. So this is why we need to use push rbp to align the stack pointer for puts subroutine.

Yes, but it is predictably misaligned, and that is important, because it means we can achieve alignment with exactly 8 bytes more space, and, restore the incoming alignment with a simple subtract.  The and operation is useful when you don't know how misaligned the stack is, but then restoring the stack pointer for return to the caller is more difficult if you don't know the misalignment that the and operation consumed.

If compiled with frame pointers off (an option in Visual Studio), there is no push rbp, but there might be a sub rsp,8.
